# How can I share mongoose models between 2 apps?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 apps, each in a different folder and they need to share the same models.

I want to symlink the models folder from app A to a models folder in app B.

I'm running into issues with the fact that once you call mongoose.model('Model', Schema) in app A, they are 'tied' to that app's mongoose/mongodb connection.

Does anyone have any tips on the best way to manage this?

Comment: When you say '2 apps' do you mean two separate node instances, each running one of those apps?

Comment: Yep, completely separate apps but they will share the same database and therefore models.

Comment: Then you shouldn't have any problems as each app will get its own set of models.  What sort of issues have you seen?

Comment: I didn't think it would be an issue either but if I require the models from appA in appB, queries never run.  The callback to a simple Model.find never gets called. There's a SO question (can't find it now) I came across where Aaron Heckman was explaining a similar issue about how models are effectively tied to a particular connection.

Comment: There must be something else going on here as I'm sure what Aaron was referring to was that calling `mongoose.model` ties that model _instance_ to the default mongoose connection.  I've shared models between apps and I haven't hit any issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I ended up doing here was importing app1 as a submodule (with Git) in app2.  This way the models can be imported as normal and are tied to the app's default `mongoose` connection.

Comment: This sounds very interesting. Can you possibly elaborate?

Comment: I am looking to do something similar. Are you still able to run the node applications independently? I want to share my user model between apps but I also want to retain the ability to run each app separately using pm2.

Comment: you could create it as an npm package like @app-name/schemas

Comment: could you please send your directory structure for more clarity? I am having similar issue and infact i also tried syslink to models but dint worked out.

Answer (score 11):

You have share your mongoose instance around by using doing something like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports.mongoose = mongoose;

var user = require('./lib/user');
```

Now inside of "lib/user.js"

```
var mongoose = module.parent.mongoose;
var model = mongoose.model('User', new mongoose.Schema({ ... });
module.exports = model;
```

So doing it like that you can require "lib/user.js" in other applications

Comment: This is a good answer. One minor tweak is that the lib/user.js file needs to refer to mongoose using module.parent.exports.mongoose. I figured this out by doing console.log(module.parent) which displays the parent module object graph.

Comment: or rather just export mongoose instance of child only... if you are importing one thing.. nothing will go wrong importing other  IDK which approach will be better though...

Answer (score 7):

My approach to sharing Mongoose models is to pass the mongoose object in as an argument to the shared module that defines the schemas and creates the models. So the file with the shared schemas/models looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(mongoose) {

    var packageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        title:          { type: String, required: true },
        description:    String
    });

    mongoose.model('Package', packageSchema, 'packages');
};
```

and then each project requires them in like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongo_url = process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(mongo_url, connectOpts);
require('../../../shared/models/packages')(mongoose);
```

Comment: I was unable to get any of the other approaches working - but this one works a treat and is more readily understandable. Literally passing the mongoose instance you want to use directly to the shared library (directly). Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to abstract the Schema into a plain JavaScript object, and then import that object to use to construct the models within your apps.

For instance, for a 'product' schema:

**www/app1/ProductConfig.js**

```
const ProductConfig = {
  name: String,
  cost: Number
}
module.exports = ProductConfig;
```

**www/app1/ProductSchema.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ProductConfig = require('./ProductConfig');

const Product = new Schema(Product);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', Product);
```

**www/app2/ProductSchema.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ProductConfig = require('../app1/ProductConfig');

const Product = new Schema(Product);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', Product);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
./shared/models/user.js

./app1/app.js
var user = require('../shared/user.js');

./app2/app.js
var user = require('../shared/user.js');
```

I dont' see why you couldn't just load the models from a shared path.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, the call to the model is fine but I got empty queries! the submodule solution works perfectly!

Comment: how did you deploy this project on server? as your shared folder might be outside of root?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to reuse your Mongoose package between other NPM packages, the best way to do it is to install the shared package at the top level app and then use it to initialize the other NPM packages.

You can use this npm module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-global