# Nodejs - Mongoose connect to a defined MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a nodejs application which is connected to a MongoDB, this application has defined its own models and schemas.

For some reason, I need to create another nodejs app which is connected to the same MongoDB the other app is connected to.

So, do I have to define the same models? Is there a way to extract the models from mongoose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I share mongoose models between 2 apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632028/how-can-i-share-mongoose-models-between-2-apps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot extract models from Mongoose like that, but what you can do is use a MongoDB connection without mongoose, depending on what you need to do.  For example:

**Do this in the other app:**

```
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/db", function(err, db) {
  if(err) { return console.dir(err); }

  var collection = db.collection('users');

    collection.find().toArray(function(err, users) {
        //users comes here.
    });    
});
```

You have not used the mongoose models here, but you have still connected to the mongodb instance with the native driver.

Check this out : https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, if in the other app there is a model for, say, users, how can I query mongoDB for finding those users?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!